# IONIC 2 : Getting syntax error

Tags: angular, ionic2

Getting syntax error while I defined a class with member variable:

```
export class SingletonService
{
student:Object;
}
```

Comment: And what's the exact error message?

Comment: "Unexpected token (4:19) while parsing file"

Comment: Probably is from another file or you have more code in this file. This code looks gooood.

Comment: This code was working in IONIC 2.0.0-beta.19 but gives syntax error in ONIC 2.0.0-beta.25!

Comment: What does the line 4 correspond to?